# ListView Retrieving Value in Code Behind File aspx.cs

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview

This issue may be simple but I am having some trouble with it. I have a listview and have an "OnItemDeleting" event set up to fire as the item is deleted. I would like to retrieve the values of the item that is being deleted in this "OnItemDeleting" event in the code behind value. Could anyone give me any tips on how to go about doing this?

===================================================================================
Listview instance in .aspx file:

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListViewMngArtwork" runat="server" Visible="true" 
        DataKeyNames="artworkID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceMngArtwork" 
        GroupItemCount="3" OnItemDeleting="ListViewMngArtwork_OnItemDeleting"/>
```

===================================================================================
Event instance in .aspx.cs file:

```
protected void ListViewMngArtwork_OnItemDeleting(object sender, EventArgs e)
{}
```

===================================================================================

Comment: What kind of trouble are you encountering?

Comment: The issue that I am encountering is that I cannot retrieve the value of a certain field in the database for the item that I am deleting. For example, I have stored in my database the file path for an image of artwork on the site. In the list view, I am able to create a delete button and delete the path from within the database. As this is deleting I want to grab the value of the path and then use that to delete the image from the server at the same time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can get the Item index, key and value in your event:

```
protected void ListViewMngArtwork_OnItemDeleting(object sender, ListViewDeleteEventArgs e)
{
    e.ItemIndex
    e.Keys
    e.Values
}
```

Comment: When I have tried to use 'e' there is no option for ItemIndex, Keys, or Values.. Any ideas on my comment above?

Comment: `e` should be `ListViewDeleteEventArgs`.

Comment: Thanks that did it- I was able to retrieve the value I needed.

e.Values["ArtThumbUrl"].ToString();